# Pass data from database to AJAX in Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, json, ajax, codeigniter-3

```
public function test()
{
    $this->load->model('m_comment');
    $comment = $this->input->post('comment');

    $insert=[
        'id_user' => '1092093',
        'isi_komentar' => $comment
    ];
        
    $data['komentar'] = $this->m_comment->getdata('komentar');
    $komentar = json_encode($data);
    echo $komentar; 

    $komentar = $this->db->get('komentar')->result();
    echo json_encode($komentar);
}
```

above is the function to get data from ajax and insert it to the database
at the bottom section im trying to get data from database and pass it to ajax, it worked perfectly

```
<body>







<h1>Article</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium maxime voluptates molestias. Repellendus eum incidunt sed, quae necessitatibus similique eveniet inventore accusantium repudiandae dolorum odio maxime reiciendis debitis aut nobis.</p>

<textarea name="komentar" id="komentar" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea> 
<input type="submit" name="submitComment" id="submitComment" value="Submit">

<br>
<p>Comments</p>
<div class="comments"></div>
<br>
<!-- <?php foreach ($komentar as $k):?>
<div id="commenWrapper"><?= '<b>'.$k['id_user'].'</b>' .' '. ':'.' ' .$k['isi_komentar'];?></div>
<?php endforeach;?> -->

<div id="commentWrap"></div>

<script>

    $('#submitComment').on('click', function () {

    
        var commentContent = $('#komentar').val();
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '<?= base_url()."main/test"?>',
            data: { comment : commentContent},
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

here is my ajax code, it worked and it worked perfectly

[alert(data) example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBqjT.png)

but somehow when i try to access a spesific data in ajax it return a '[', like it was reading a string

code look like this

```
<script>

    $('#submitComment').on('click', function () {

    
        var commentContent = $('#komentar').val();
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '<?= base_url()."main/test"?>',
            data: { comment : commentContent},
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data[0]);
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

and the result

[logging a spesific index from the array?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7K8U.png)

if i try to access spesific data with an index

like this

```
console.log(data[0].id_user);
```

the return in console is 'undefined'

[console result undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Swtx9.png)

update : i figured it out and things works fine now

Comment: _"like it was reading a string"_ - yes, that's what it does, if your server did not explicitly specify that it was responding with JSON via the Content-Type header. If you don't want to parse the string yourself, then tell jQuery what kind of data format you are expecting, via the `dataType` parameter, https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: i set a new parameter `dataType` with value JSON in ajax, it give me an error saying json is not defined

Comment: You need to show us what you actually did, instead of giving just a vague explanation. Right now, I am _guessing_ that you probably tried `dataType: json` ...? Well that would of course refer to a _variable_ named `json`, which you don't have.

Comment: if `dataType: 'json'` in the ajax code didn't help, then it is possible your PHP code prints something before it prints the encoded JSON object, which will basically invalidate that JSON string. Check the XHR request in your browsers dev tools (open Dev Tools -> click Network -> perform the ajax call -> click on the request you performed -> see 'Preview') https://imgur.com/a/r6jlr94

Comment: yes i typed in `dataType : 'json',` how do i fix this, am i missing a library or something else?